# How come my Apache can only access root owned files?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, centos, file-permissions

Running apache on centos 6.4 and my web server can't see any files unless the root user creates or copies them.

`ps aux | grep apache` shows that apache is running as apache user, not root.
I tried `chown apache:apache` on the files.
I even set `chmod 777` on the files.

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 2300 May 15 17:46 example.php
```

I still get an http 500 error, what else could be wrong?

also even if I chown the file to root:root, it will not work, I need to actually `cp file.php file.php` as root before it will work. I don't get it!

`chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t example.php` gets me there! - thanks Chris.
Does this mean I need to change my FTP user's Security Context settings so they can upload files like this or do I need to change a rule in SELinux to allow a wider range of files to execute?

Comment: I get "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0" for files that don't work and "unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0" for files that do work. Disabling SELinux does allow the file to be accessed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux might here be a problem.

Please do `ls -lZ example.php`

To rule out SELinux you can:

```
getenforce
```

then

```
setenforce 0
```

And try accessing this file again...

That will temporarily put SELinux in permissive mode.
You might have to change a context of the file! Let us know how it goes and we will take it from there.

**Update:**

As expected, SELinux was stopping apache from accessing that file. If you trust this file, you can change it's context:

```
chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t example.php
```

If there is more than one file, you could use `-R` flag, so:

```
chcon -vR --type=httpd_sys_content_t /html/
```

As you have noticed, with `ls` you have `-Z` flag to show SELlinux context. You can try using this flag with other programs like `ps` for example.

To troubleshoot SELinux problems I recommend `sealert` - part of `setroubleshoot-server`.

How did I know that you are most likely using SELinux? Your filesystem is labeled.
How did i know that your fs is labeled? `-rwxrwxrwx**.**` - dot at the end of permissions tells that fs is labeled.

Don't forget to change the permissions! You really don't want 777...
Hope that helps.

Comment: I get "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0" for files that don't work and "unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0" for files that do work. Disabling SELinux does allow the file to be accessed correctly

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, you saved me a TON of headache. I will start looking into sealert per your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

If you have enabled suphp then files with 777 permissions will not work fine and give 500 error, change the permissions 644.

Also check error log for the same if you are still facing same issue.

Why are you trying 'cp file.php file.php' with same name, to copy use other name as below or copy to another location where file.php not exists.

> cp file.php file.php-bak

or

> cp file.php another-dir/file.php

Comment: I'm not sure what suphp is, but I don't think I enabled it? I simply observed that making a copy of the file as root user made them function correctly. Also 644 permission did not work