# git-http-backend with apache2.4 Centos 7

Tags: git, apache, centos7

I try to set up a Git-server on my apache server but it dont work!
I got the following git.conf

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/html/git/project1
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory "/var/www/html/git/project1">
   Options ExecCGI Indexes
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Git Access"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/html/git/users/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

I created a user but I cant acces the site.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /git/ on this server.
```

If I comment line 3

```
#ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

Now I can acces the site and can see the git repository. Does anyone know how I can fix this.
English isn't my first language so please be patient with my text.
Thanks for reading  best regards
Sam

Comment: Did you manage to debug your setup, after our interactive session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [`git http-backend` doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend):

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
```

This should be the root folder under which you have git repos (repo1.git, repo2.git, ...). It should not be `/git/project1`, which looks like the name of a repo itself.

So try the example:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    Require group committers
    ...
</LocationMatch>
```

Note: after an interactive session, it turns out you need to be sure that:

- the data read or served by apache are owned by apache:apache (chown -R)
- [SElinux (Security-Enhanced Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) allows the httpd service to read Z: ls -Z

If the later point does not include httd_rw, you need to type (as in "[How come my Apache can only access root owned files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582164/6309)"), to change its context:

```
chcon -vR --type=httpd_sys_content_t /html/
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I tryed your solution but nothing change. I can't see the website and it dont ask me for a username or password

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy Remeber: this is for git clone/git push, that has nothing to do with seeing website.

Comment: Hey ok. I tryed to push something to the repository but i get the following error "fatal: unable to access 'http://sam@172.16.67.131/git/project1/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy Did you authenticate?

Comment: what do you mean? :) I try to push with "git push origin master" and normaly it should ask me for a password? But I just get the error

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy yes: read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend: "In this mode, the server will not request authentication until the client actually starts the object negotiation phase of the push, rather than during the initial contact. For this reason, you must also enable the http.receivepack config option in any repositories that should accept a push. **The default behavior, if http.receivepack is not set, is to reject any pushes by unauthenticated users; the initial request will therefore report 403 Forbidden to the client, without even giving an opportunity for authentication.**"

Comment: Yeah I read this. I enabled it the config file of the repository [core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[http]
       receivepack = true
        uploadpack = true

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy well, in this example, the user sam should be part of the group "committer". Is it? Is sam an account which exists on the server *and* is part of the group committer?

Comment: Ok there is not a account with the name sam. I thought "AuthUserFile /var/www/html/git/users/.htpasswd" will tell who can acces the repository. There is a user sam with a password saved in .htpasswd. What else I have to do?

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy to simplify, you can remove the Require directive to see if that is enough for the authentication to proceed.

Comment: So I did "# Require group committers  # Require valid-user" but I get the same error if I try to push

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy Can you clone at least?

Comment: No I cant "fatal: repository 'sam@172.16.67.131/git/project1' does not exist"

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy then you need to solve that first. Note that this setup allows for anonymous cloning/fetching. It is only the push which requires authentication.

Comment: Ok. Some tips? I dont know where to start.

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy I have to go for a few hours, but try following https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend first, with no authentication at first, just to see if that is working. If not, ping me, and we'll see if we can set up together an Hangout session (with screen sharing)

Comment: Hey im back home now and I will try this now. How i ping you here?:)

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy I am back too. Can you ping me on hangout and share you screen that way?

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy If not, you can install http://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/, and communicate your id => interactive session that way.

Comment: Server:979 662 253 pwd:795njv