# Apache git server with Alpine Linux on Docker

Tags: git, apache, docker, alpine-linux, gitweb

I am trying to serve git repos over `http` using Alpine's Apache image in Docker.

I am able to get Apache to serve up documents and folders over `http` (there are some non git repos in this folder, this is just a proof of concept at the moment, so they can be ignored):

[image: docker alpine apache git]

However when I attempt to clone the git repo's, I can only successfully clone the `DynamicDockerTesting.git` repo. When attempting to clone the other repo's I get

```
fatal: repository 'http://192.168.1.32/<repo-name>.git' not found
```

I have inspected every difference I can think of between `DynamicDockerTesting.git` and the other repo's present, but have not been able to find any meaningful difference that would explain why I can clone that particular repo, but none of the other ones. If you have suggestions as to how to figure out why this is the case I would love to hear them, but more importantly if you know what I am doing wrong in general, and how to deploy these repo's successfully using the docker-alpine-apache-git combination, I would be extremely grateful.

Here are the contents of my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM httpd:alpine 

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/apache2/git
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add git git-gitweb apache2-utils apache2
COPY apacheGitServer.xml  /usr/local/apache2/
RUN cat /usr/local/apache2/apacheGitServer.xml >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -i '/LoadModule alias_module modules\/mod_alias.so/aLoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Alpine Apache seems to run everything out of `/usr/local/apache2` (instead of `/etc/apache2`), so here I am just adding to the default `httpd.conf` the logic to deploy the repos, and also enabling the `cgi` module since it is disabled by default (`env` and `alias` are enabled by default).

Here are the contents of `apacheGitServer.xml`

```
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/apache2/git/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/git
    ServerName 192.168.1.32

    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/git">
        Allow from All
        Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    </Directory>

    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /usr/local/apache2/git
    ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
    #ScriptAlias / /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi
</VirtualHost>
```

`apacheGitServer.xml` has gone through a number of revisions as I have tried every configuration that I could think of to get this working, but to no avail. This configuration makes the repos accessible, but not clone-able (except, of course `DynamicDockerTesting.git`)

With the `Dockerfile` and `apacheGitServer.xml` in the same folder, I have been building the image with

`docker build -t apachegit .`

and then I have `cd`'ed to the directory with my git repo's, and issued the command

`docker run -d --name apachegitserver -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/local/apache2/git apachegit`

I have spent two days trying to get this to work, so any guidance at this point is welcome.

EDIT

[image: top command inside container]

running `top` I see that the process is owned by `daemon`, I have `cd`'ed to `/usr/local/apache2/git` from inside the container and run `chown -R daemon:daemon .`, but now when I clone:

`git clone http://192.168.1.32/git/ScalaOpenCV.git`

I get a `403`:

`fatal: unable to access 'http://192.168.1.32/git/<repo name>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

(actually I get a `403` no matter if I change the permissions or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am finally able to clone over http. This is what finally worked:

1) put all the git repos in the default deploy folder (`/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`) using the docker `-v` flag from my original question post.

2) Modify the default `httpd.conf` for the alpine image and add the following:

2a) `<Directory "usr/local/apache2/htdocs">` node now has:
`Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI` (not sure if the `FollowSymLinks` option in necessary)

2b) No need to add a `<VirtualHost>` node

2c) add the following settings to the config: 
`SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /usr/local/apache2/htdocs`, 
`SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL`, 
`ScriptAlias / /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/` 
(Obviously, this is all pretty standard stuff from other postings about how to set up an Apache Git server)

2d) Comment in `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so`

2e) Add the following `Directory` node:

```
<Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core">
   Options +ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**I DO NOT KNOW HOW SECURE THESE CONFIGURATIONS ARE**

Now when I navigate locally to the container's IP address, the browser gives me a `404`, that there is nothing to serve. However, if I attempt to clone, git finds the repos and clones just fine.

I am cloning from the root context, ie `http://<ip address>/<git repo>.git`.

I am still working to figure out why the browser is not indexing the repo's for display, but at least the core need (cloning over http) is working.

Comment: I remember doing that with a ScriptAlias (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098812/6309), but if this work here in your case, then +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```

That means any git operation should involve an URL with `/git/` in it (as shown in [this setup](https://blog.mapstrata.com/post/gitweb/)).

```
git clone http://192.168.1.32/git/<repo-name>.git
```

Check the apache logs to see if there is any difference between  `DynamicDockerTesting.git` and the others. Check the ownership, as [shown here](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/08/05/git-setup-a-bare-repository-which-is-writable-by-both-user-and-group/).

Comment: thank you for the answer. You were absolutely right about needing to add `/git/` to the URL path. When I run apache locally (outside of docker) I can clone now over `http` just fine. Inside docker however I keep getting a `403` however, even after changing the user permissions (I also get a `403` when attempting to clone `DynamicDockerTesting.git`, so at least the error is consistent now). Would you have any ideas about how to correctly configure ownership in this case?